# How to create separate column of filtered data in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table(name) in which column has value like this

```
field1| field2
---------------
F_name | Arya
L_name | Amar
F_name | Karan
l_name | Roy
```

here I want to display first and last name like this

```
field | field 
-------------
Amar  | Arya
Karan | Roy
```

Is it possible to create this type of column in sql

Comment: What database are you using? Also, how do you know which names belong together? Is there another field that can be used to tie first and last together?  It'll be a conditional aggregate or a `PIVOT` depending on db.

Comment: and what connects a given F_name to the corresponding L_name? in other words, how do you tell that "Arya" goes with "Amar" rather than "Roy"?

Comment: This is called pivoting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some sort of field that ties the names together, like `NameID` you can use a conditional aggregate via `CASE` expression and `GROUP BY` your field that ties the names together:

```
SELECT NameID
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN field1 = 'F_NAME' THEN field2 END) AS F_Name
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN field1 = 'L_NAME' THEN field2 END) AS L_Name
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY NameID
```

Depending on DB, you may have `PIVOT` available as well.

Comment: Yes, there is also another column called     post_id and value related to separate user derail is smae. Means f_name and l_name has same value of post id.

Comment: @AmarArya So where I used `NameID` just replace it with `post_id` and this should do the trick, and you can follow the example to add `Country` too.

Comment: but here I'm also getting `null` value and How can remove those null value

Comment: I don't see any `NULL` values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59a442/1/0 Need more information to understand the issue, maybe you need to filter out some `Post_id` records?